# AngularJS recursive function call with $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I have created a recursive function call in AngularJS and just wonder is there a better way to solve this porblem?

My code is the following:

```
function getLocation(query, map, object, delay) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch({ query: query }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var loc = results[0].geometry.location;
            object.lang = loc.lng();
            object.lat = loc.lat();
            deferred.resolve(object);
        } else {
            if (status === "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
                delay += 100;
                deferred.resolve($timeout(function () {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    getLocation(query, map, object, delay).then(function (object) {
                        deferred.resolve(object);
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }, delay));
            } else {
                deferred.reject(status);
            }
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just place the `deferred.resolve` call **inside** the timeout ?

Comment: Already tried it before, but didn't solve my problem and hadn't wait.

Comment: delay is in milliseconds.  you are incrementing by order of 100 ms, try using it in seconds (multiplying 1000).  [Refer the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: If this code works, and is your own code, and you're willing to submit all of it to review, this *might* be better on [codereview.se]. Please do check out their [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to be sure your question is on-topic there.

Comment: Mahesh, this code works perfectly, the problem is that it looks ugly for me. Mike McCaughan, thanks for you advice, I will try to review my code on codereview!

Answer (score 0):

when you call `deferred.resolve($timeout(function () { ...`, you are saying that your promise function is successfully resolved and you return $timeout (which by its self is a promise) promise object, instead of expected `{lang:..., lat:...}` object. It does not sound correct. Then you starting a new call to promise function within `$timeout`.

I would try to return $timeout promise, instead of resolving it, and call `getLocation(...)` function within `$timeout.then()`, also I would return `deferred.resolve(object)` instead of execution:

```
function getLocation(query, map, object, delay) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch({ query: query }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var loc = results[0].geometry.location;
        object.lang = loc.lng();
        object.lat = loc.lat();
        return deferred.resolve(object);
    } else if (status === "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
      delay += 100;
      return $timeout(function () {}, delay).then(function () {
        return getLocation(query, map, object, delay);
      });
    } else {
      deferred.reject(status);
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Hey Andriy,

Like I mentioned before, this function works perfectly fine. Your solution is not correct, because you won't resolve your promise in case of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT! The problem for me is this solution is a bit ugly for my eyes :)